# Only one calendar shown in GCal in Calendar in Mac

Tags: macos, mac, google-calendar, calendar.app

I've been searching answers for hours but cannot find one.

There're several calendars in my Google Calendar. I want to sync all of them with my iCal (or "Calendar" in the newest Mountain Lion). But after I set up my account I can only see one calendar from my google account (the default one). I wonder is there a way to sync all the calendars in my google account?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Calendar *Preferences…*, then view *Accounts*.
2. Click on your Google account.
3. In the left hand pane there are 2 tabs: '*Account Information*' and '*Delegation*'.
4. Click on *Delegation*: you'll find all the other subscribed calendars there.
5. Tick the boxes for the additional calendars you want, and they'll all turn up in Calendar.